# For loop in php not appending new data to array

Tags: php

I have paginated data returned and I am using the meta data to try to create an array with all data from every page returned. In my loop I get the proper data count meaning the page increments correctly but I get back the same data as a duplicate. Am I not looping properly?

```
    $totalResults = [];

    for ($currentPage = $body['current_page']; $currentPage <= $body['last_page']; $currentPage++) {
                    $totalResults[$currentPage] = $body;
                }
    
                var_dump($totalResults);
```

It returns an array with 5 items in it, one array per page in this case but every array of data contains duplicate data and the `current_page` always remains as `1`.

Output of `$body` (truncated for readability)

```
^ array:13 [
  "current_page" => 1
  "data" => array:15 [
    0 => array:5 [
      "id" => 1
      "name" => "John Smith"
      "title" => "Developer"
      "created_at" => "2021-06-02"
      "updated_at" => "2021-06-02"
    ]
    ....Returns 15 at a time
  ]
  "first_page_url" => "http://localhost/api/users?page=1"
  "from" => 1
  "last_page" => 4
  "last_page_url" => "http://localhost/api/users?page=4"
  "per_page" => 15
  "prev_page_url" => null
  "to" => 15
  "total" => 60
]
```

Comment: Inside your loop, you're assigning from `$body` which is (apparently) the entire result set, not the data for one page. Post the contents of `$body`.

Comment: @AlexHowansky I have updated with the output of `$data`

Comment: Have you already fetched all 4 pages or just the first one?  If only the first then you need code to get the next pages.

Comment: @AbraCadaver just the first page to begin with and then from there I am trying to increment as I loop to then fetch all subsequent data and place it in a single array

Comment: I'm guessing you want something like this: `$totalResults[$currentPage] = $body['data'][$currentPage - $body['currentPage']];` -- then you'll get the data for page N in `$totalResults[N]`. (I presume you're then looping this loop to get multiple sets of pages.)

Comment: In your loop you need to do something like `$body = file_get_contents('http://localhost/api/users?page='.$currentPage+1);` or something to get the next body.

Comment: @AlexHowansky ultimately what I want is to gather all `$body['data']` from all pages and place it all into one single array.

Comment: @AlexHowansky can you place your answer in an answer below so I can accept it and up vote if it resolves the issue?

Comment: The next page url would just have a 2 appended at the end similar to last page url

Comment: Did you give up?

Answer (score 0):

You're just using the same `$body` from the first page over and over, so you need to check and fetch the next page in the loop:

```
$body = file_get_contents('http://localhost/api/users?page=' . $currentPage+1);

for ($currentPage = $body['current_page']; $currentPage <= $body['last_page']; $currentPage++) {
    $totalResults[$currentPage] = $body['data'];
    $body = file_get_contents('http://localhost/api/users?page=' . $currentPage+1);
}
```

You could do it like this as well:

```
$body = file_get_contents('http://localhost/api/users');

while($body['current_page'] <= $body['last_page']) {
    $totalResults[$body['current_page']] = $body['data'];
    $body = file_get_contents('http://localhost/api/users?page=' . $body['current_page']+1);
}
```

Or without the first fetch:

```
$body['current_page'] = 0;
while($body = file_get_contents('http://localhost/api/users?page=' . $body['current_page']+1) &&
      $body['current_page'] <= $body['last_page'])
{

      $totalResults[$body['current_page']] = $body['data'];
}
```

If I misunderstand and all pages are in the array that you show then just extract the `data` and index on `current_page`:

```
$totalResults = array_column($body, 'data', 'current_page');
```

Comment: So in your example your url is already broken up whereas my url endpoint has the page=1 as part of the string already

Comment: Well you need to be able to increment it, do it however.  I don’t see a next_page in your example array.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing this:

```
$totalResults[$currentPage] = $body;
```

But `$body` contains the data for *all* the records in this result set, not just one record, so you're repeatedly setting array entries to a copy of the whole array.

Assuming you get the results in order, you can just append the current set of records to your total so far. Pseudo code:

```
do {
  get the next page
  pull the records out and append them to your total
} while (that wasn't last page)
```

In PHP, something like:

```
$page = 1;
$allRecords = [];
do {
    $result = get_page($page);
    array_push($allRecords, ...$result['data']);
    $page = $result['current_page'] + 1;
} while ($result['current_page'] < $result['last_page']);
```